# Duplicate Dynamic PrimeNg drop down using Angular 12 + reactive form Array

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a task to add prime ng drop down by angular reactive form array, while add drop down in row, previous selected value should not populated
as well as while delete any drop down from row that delete options value should available for other drop downs, I have tried enclosed code but no luck
[image]

```
app.component.html
=======================

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>   
       <div
      formArrayName="credentials"
      *ngFor="let creds of addDynamicRow?.controls; let i = index"
    >
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <p-dropdown
          [options]="cities"
          placeholder="Select a City"
          optionLabel="name"
          optionValue="type"
          formControlName="filterSelection"
          (onChange)="selected($event,i)"
        ></p-dropdown>
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <br>
  <br>
  <button (click)="addCreds()">Add</button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <button (click)="deleteCreds()">Delete</button>

</form>

app.component.ts
================

import { Component, ElementRef, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

interface City {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  key: string;
  type: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  cities!: City[];
  form!: FormGroup;
  @ViewChildren('selectFilter') filterSelects!: QueryList<
    ElementRef<HTMLSelectElement>
  >;
  dynamicForm!: FormGroup;
  selectedLangs = new Set<string>();
  skillsForSelectedPath: any = [];

  ngOninit() {}
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      credentials: this.fb.array([this.filterItemRow()]),
    });

    this.cities = [
      {
        id: 20,
        name: 'abc',
        key: 'abc',
        type: 'abc',
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        name: 'def',
        key: 'def',
        type: 'def',
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'ghi',
        key: 'ghi',
        type: 'ghi',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'jkl',
        key: 'jkl',
        type: 'jkl',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'mno',
        key: 'mno',
        type: 'mno',
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        name: 'pqr',
        key: 'pqr',
        type: 'pqr',
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        name: 'stu',
        key: 'stu',
        type: 'stu',
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        name: 'vwx',
        key: 'vwx',
        type: 'vwx',
      },
      {
        id: 17,
        name: 'yza',
        key: 'yza',
        type: 'yza',
      },
      {
        id: 14,
        name: 'Days Down',
        key: 'daysDown',
        type: 'daysdown',
      },
     
      
    ];
  }
  addCreds() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.filterItemRow());
  }
  filterItemRow() {
    return this.fb.group({
      filterSelection: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
  get addDynamicRow(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('credentials') as FormArray;
  }
  getSkillFormGroup(index: number): FormGroup {
    const formGroup = this.form.controls[index] as FormGroup;
    return formGroup;
  }
  selected(event: any, i: number) {

   // this.cities = this.cities.filter((x) => x.type != event.value);
  }

  deleteCreds(){
    
  }
}
```

Please suggest the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code; I hope I have shown you a new way.

```
selected(event, index) {
        console.log(event);
        this.selectedLangs.add(event.value.name);
        this.skillsForSelectedPath[index] = event.value.name;
        this.cities = this.cities.filter((city) => city.name !== event.value);
      }

  deleteCreds() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
    creds.removeAt(0);
    const selectedCity = this.cities.find(
      (city) => city.name === this.selectedLangs.values().next().value
    );
    this.cities.splice(this.cities.indexOf(selectedCity), 1);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-eqyzqq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Behram Bazo thanks for response. selected values going off in dropdown from shared code but selected value should persist in drop down